# Getting entries from StackOverflow atom feed

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath, atom-feed

I feel like an idiot for asking this question again, as I know it's been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501171/no-nodes-selected-from-atom-xml-document-using-xpath) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734/selectnodes-not-working-on-stackoverflow-feed) times.  I cannot for the life of me get this code working even with the answers that have already been provided, so I'm hoping that by offering my current code, someone can help me determine where I'm going wrong:

```
Dim RSSReader As New Xml.XmlTextReader("https://stackoverflow.com/feeds")
Dim RSSDoc As New Xml.XmlDocument()

Dim NSMgr As New Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(RSSDoc.NameTable)
NSMgr.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
RSSDoc.Load(RSSReader.GetRemainder())
RSSReader.Close()

For Each Node As Xml.XmlNode In RSSDoc.SelectNodes("atom:entry", NSMgr)
    AddAtomMessage(Account, Node)
Next
```

Based on the above code the "AddAtomMessage" method never gets executed as no nodes are returns by "SelectNodes" on the For/Each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is wrong. You want

```
//atom:entry
```

or (more specific is better)

```
/atom:feed/atom:entry
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I thought I didn't need the initial forward slash if I wanted to search anywhere in the XML.