# XPath for XML with namespace

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I have an xml with various namespaces that i would like to query using .SelectNodes(string xPath)

The problem that i notice is that the xPath query return nothing as long as i have all those namespaces around.

1. is there anyway to tell XmlDocument.SelectNodes to ignore those namespaces and just get me the correct elements (the elements that i query doesn't seem to have namespaces prefix)?
2. if there is, can anyone please provide me an example of how to do it? what should i defined before/when i query the nodes?

Thanks for the help.

Correction: i still can't figure what the problem is. here is my xml:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"  xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/"  xmlns:gf="http://schemas.google.com/finance/2007"  
      xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" >
  <id>http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/xyx@google.com/portfolios</id>
  <updated>2009-12-15T19:32:21.000Z</updated>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"  term="http://schemas.google.com/finance/2007#portfolio" />
  <title type="text" >Portfolio Feed</title>
  <link rel="alternate"  type="text/html"  href="http://finance.google.com/finance/portfolio?action=view" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed"  type="application/atom+xml"  href="http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/default/portfolios" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post"  type="application/atom+xml"  href="http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/default/portfolios" />
  <link rel="self"  type="application/atom+xml"  href="http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/default/portfolios" />
  <openSearch:totalResults>24</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>24</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <entry>
    <id>http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/xyx@google.com/portfolios/2</id>
    <updated>2009-12-14T16:26:53.000Z</updated>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"  term="http://schemas.google.com/finance/2007#portfolio" />
    <title type="text" >Main</title>
    <link rel="self"  type="application/atom+xml"  href="http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/default/portfolios/2" />
    <link rel="edit"  type="application/atom+xml"  href="http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/default/portfolios/2" />
    <gd:feedLink href="http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/xyx@google.com/portfolios/2/positions" />
    <gf:portfolioData currencyCode="USD"  gainPercentage="0.0"  return1w="0.0"  return1y="0.0"  return3m="0.0"  return3y="0.0"  return4w="0.0"  return5y="0.0"  returnOverall="0.0"  returnYTD="0.0" />
  </entry>
</feed>
```

and here is my code:

XmlDocument xml = ExecuteRequest(url);

```
        var xmlnsManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("xmlns:openSearch", "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/");
        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("xmlns:gf", "http://schemas.google.com/finance/2007");
        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("xmlns:gd", "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005");

        var nodes = xml.SelectNodes("//feed/entry", xmlnsManager);
```

and my nodes count is still 0! any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found the problem in another post here:
[No Nodes Selected from Atom XML document using XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501171/no-nodes-selected-from-atom-xml-document-using-xpath)

thanks everybody.

Comment: Link-only answers are poor answers.  You should include the substantive content from the linked answer.  However, in this case, once you do that, your answer will resemble [Darrel Miller's answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2075794/2704659), which, in my opinion, should be the accepted answer here, not yours.

Answer (score 9):

You need to create a namespace manager, setup all the namespaces that you want to use and their prefix and then in the XPath, you need to use the prefix.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load("myfile.xml");

var xmlnsManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://example.org/schema.xsd");

doc.SelectNodes("//ns:MyElement",xmlnsManager);
```

Warning: I did not compile this code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not as familiar with the .NET api, but you might be able to send in a more generic XPATH that ignores namespaces by matching on any element(e.g. `*`) and using the `local-name` in the predicate filters.

e.g. using `/*[local-name()='foo']/*[local-name()='bar']/*[local-name()='baz']`
to find `ns:foo/ns:bar/ns:baz` without declaring the **ns** namespace.

That way you don't have to bind to a particular namespace at compile time and can pass in arbritrary XPATH statements.

Obviously, by using namespace-unaware XPATH statements you could get unintended results(if there is mixed namespace content with elements of the same name) and the XPATH is really  verbose.

In **XPATH 2.0** you can use wildcards for namespaces: `/*:foo/*:bar/*:baz` , but you would have to use [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) to get **XSLT/XPATH 2.0** support in .NET.

Comment: Actually, Altova have a free XSLT 2.0 processor that is COM based but could be accessed from .Net. (http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) and Intel recently released XSLT 2.0 processor that runs on 64bit windows. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-soa-expressway-xslt-20-processor/