# -[NSXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] returns empty array while it should not

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, xpath, nsxmlelement

I am trying to parse an Atom feed. I have extended `NSXMLNode` with this method through a category:

```
- (NSString *)stringValueForNodeAtXPath:(NSString *)XPath error:(NSError **)error {
  NSArray *nodes = [self nodesForXPath:XPath error:error];
  if ([nodes count] == 0) { return nil; }
  return [[nodes lastObject] stringValue];
}
```

This method returns the string value of a node when only one node is expected.

An Atom feed's entry looks like this:

```
<entry>
  <title>A title</title>
  <id>Unique id</id>
</entry>
```

I have an `NSXMLElement` object like the one above. However, when trying to get either the `title` or the `id` of the `entry`, `-[NSXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:]` returns an empty array (and therefor my extension returns `nil`):

```
_uniqueId = [[XMLElement stringValueForNodeAtXPath:@"/entry/id" error:error] copy];
```

What could be the problem? Is my XPath query wrong? There is clearly an `id` in the `entry`, and `entry` is the root element.

---

<sub><sup>Yes, `NSLog`-ing `XMLElement` confirms my last sentence.</sup></sub>

Comment: Seems like there is a default namespace in your real sourceXML document. It is the most FAQ how to write XPath expressions for nodes in an XML document that has a default namespace. Just search "xpath default namespace".

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath with GDataXMLNode in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138142/xpath-with-gdataxmlnode-in-objective-c)

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501171/no-nodes-selected-from-atom-xml-document-using-xpath