# XPath with GDataXMLNode in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xpath, gdataxml

I am making an iOS app where I'm using the GDataXML library for xml parsing in Objective C.

I have the following xml (that I get as an soap response):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <MakeRequestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <MakeRequestResult>SOMERANDOMDATAHERE012912033905345346</MakeRequestResult>
      </MakeRequestResponse>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

The problem I have is:

when I write the xpath expression for the given xml like this I get the MakeRequestResponse node:

```
NSArray *listOfNodes = [[responseDocument rootElement] nodesForXPath:@"soap:Body/*" error:&error];
```

However I'm unable to get this node or any children below when I write the actual node name:

```
NSArray *listOfNodes = [[responseDocument rootElement] nodesForXPath:@"soap:Body/MakeRequestResponse" error:&error];
```

I'm not sure what is the issue here. Could it be an namespace related issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is a FAQ** (search for XPath and default namespace).

The short answer is that when an XPath expression is evaluated, any unprefixed names are assumed to be in "no namespace". But `MakeRequestResponse` is not in "no namespace" and thus isn't selected.

**Solution**:

Either register the `"http://tempuri.org/"` namespace and associate a prefix (say `"x:"`) to it, then use:

```
soap:Body/x:MakeRequestResponse
```

Or, otherwise you can have an expression like this:

```
soap:Body/*[name() = 'MakeRequestResponse']
```

Comment: As I see, the "issue" is actually in the xml document itself. The right way of doing it would be to change the xml. The other one is working, but it seems a bit of a quirk. Thanks

Comment: @Luka - I'm a little late here, but, no, the error is not "*actually in the xml document itself*". Re-read Dimitre's solution.

Comment: @_Luka: @lwburk is completely right -- it is OK (not a problem) for XML documents or fragments to be in a default namespace.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I agree that it is ok for the xml documents to be in a default namespace. However, as you've explained the 'MakeRequestResponse' element in my example is neither in a default no-namespace (because it has an xmlns attribute which defines an custom namespace) neither it is in a accessible namespace (because it does not have an prefix associated with the xmlns attribute). From what I've seen on this site, some other xml libraries treat cases like mine as a no-namespace elements, since the definition (xmlns) without a prefix is not correct. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Luka: These "some other xml libraries" are clearly non-compliant and it is a good idea to avoid them. Re-defining the default namespace at any element in the XML document is a standard feature of XML Namespaces. From the W3C spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting): "*default namespace declaration extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag, excluding the scope of any inner default namespace declarations. In the case of an empty tag, the scope is the tag itself*."

Comment: I was banging my head against this problem for hours.  Thanks very much for the solution.