# Null object reading from XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlreader

I am trying to read in a simple xml file but am having some issues.  Here is the code to read it:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("C:/file.xsd");

    XmlNode loc = doc.SelectSingleNode("/schema/annotation/appinfo");
    XmlNodeList refNode= loc.SelectNodes("referral");
```

And here is what the XML looks like:

```
<schema>
  <annotation>
   <appinfo>
     <referral/>
     <referral/>
     <referral/>
   </appinfo>
  </annotation>
</schema>
```

I've simplified it for readabilities sake, but I am trying to read in the 'referral' nodes.  I confirmed that the file is being read in however the 'loc' variable is null.

Would appreciate some help with this, thanks!

Comment: is there a namespace in the un-simplified version? like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734/selectnodes-not-working-on-stackoverflow-feed

Comment: no namespaces, the name of the nodes are exactly as listed (just removed attributes here)

Comment: give doc.SelectSingleNode("schema/annotation/appinfo"); a try. (remove leading slash)

Comment: What's the full error? where in your code is it happening?

Comment: To add on to Jonesy I notice that you reference an xsd which most always has a namespace.  Adding a namespace manager as shown in the question he referenced should suffice  Example:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

Answer (score 0):

Following code giving correct results, so there is no problem with selecting nodes by given path. i think you have to add correct namespace to work.

```
string xml = @"<schema>
                <annotation>
                <appinfo>
                    <referral/>
                    <referral/>
                    <referral/>
                </appinfo>
                </annotation>
            </schema>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNode loc = doc.SelectSingleNode("/schema/annotation/appinfo");
XmlNodeList refNode = loc.SelectNodes("referral");
```