# Interfacing with a mySQL database with C/C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to communicate with a MySQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901/what-is-the-best-way-to-communicate-with-a-mysql-server)

Is there a simple way to access and modify a mySQL database on a Web Site or XAMMP using C/C++? How is this usually done? If a library is needed, is there one that is not extremely difficult to compile and use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used either, but there is a C API [that comes with MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c.html), and if you prefer C++, there's also a [C++ wrapper available](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/).

Answer (score 1):

From section 19.8 of the MySQL documentation:

The C API code is distributed with MySQL. It is included in the mysqlclient library and enables C programs to access a database.

Many of the clients in the MySQL source distribution are written in C. If you are looking for examples that demonstrate how to use the C API, take a look at these clients. You can find these in the client directory in the MySQL source distribution.

-- this can be found at this URL
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html